# How to simplify Postgres UPDATE query?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table, which can be simplified to this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE products
(
    id serial primary key,
    product_id  varchar
)
```

In `product_id` column stored some data with format `Product-somestring`. In some rows, `Product` can start from the `UPPERCASE` and contain `-` as a delimiter. The goal is to `UPDATE` all the rows and change first part (splitted by `-`) of `product_id` value to `LOWERCASE`.

I see 2 cases:

1. Where we have 1 `-`
2. Where we have 2 or more `-`

I gave birth to this huge and ugly query (but it works):

```sql
UPDATE products
SET product_id =
    CASE
        WHEN array_length(string_to_array(product_id, '-'), 1) >= 2 THEN array_to_string(array_replace(string_to_array(product_id, '-'), (string_to_array(product_id, '-'))[1], LOWER((string_to_array(product_id, '-'))[1])),'-')
        WHEN array_length(string_to_array(product_id, '-'), 1) = 1 THEN LOWER(product_id)

    END
WHERE product_id ~ '[[:upper:]]';
```

#### My question is:

How can it be simplified or what is the correct way of solving this problem?

Comment: You can simplify it, if you properly normalize your data model. Don't store delimited values in a single column.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But, unfortunately, at least for now, data model can't be changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
update product
set product_id = replace(product_id,substring(product_id,1,position('-' in product_id)), lower(substring(product_id,1,position('-' in product_id))));
```